# 8 rooks puzzle with missing squares

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Suppose you want to place 8 rooks on a standard chessboard so that non of the rooks would attack each other, also there are some squares missing, meaning that a rook cannot be placed on a square if it is missing, for example, let’s say a1, a2, c3, d2, g5 and h8 are missing (the rooks can attack each other as long as they are on the same file or rank, even if there are missing squares between them), assume that each solution is equally likely, what is the probability that a rook lands on e5, given that the sample space is all the possible solutions to the non-attacking rooks on the board with missing squares?

I was able to solve this problem manually on on boards with lower dimensions.

Comment: Google "rook polynomial"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can compute the number of ways of placing $n$ rooks on an $n\times n$ chessboard with missing squares, the problem is solved, because the number of ways to do so with a rook on E5 (supposing that E5 is not missing) is the number of ways to place $n-1$ rooks on the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ board formed by deleting column E and row 5.

One way to compute this number is to compute the [rook polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial) of the boards, but that gives you more information that you need.

If we only care about the number of ways to place $n$ rooks, we can compute the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) of the $n\times n$ $(0,1)$ matrix formed by representing each cell with a rook in it by a $1$ and each empty cell by a $0$.  An advantage of this approach is that computer algebra systems will have a built-in function for computing the permanent of a matrix.